# What is a "treatment firm"?

Tags: meaning

What is a "treatment firm"?

> Further, propensity score matching is a more robust method of matching that quantitative accounting researchers  frequently use (Rosenbaum & Rubin, 1983). With this technique, the researcher first estimates a logit or probit regression  with the treatment effect as the dependent variable (i.e., S&P 500 membership, continuing with our earlier example) and  independent variables that are known determinants of the treatment (possibly economic performance, firm size, age, industry, etc. in our example). From this first-stage regression, the researcher obtains propensity scores.
>
> 6 The researcher  then matches each treated observation to a non-treated observation based on the distance between their propensity scores  i.e., those observations with the closest propensity scores are matched).
>
> 7 Hoi et al. (2013) utilize propensity score matching in their study that links irresponsible CSR activities with tax aggressiveness. They first generate predicted propensity scores     for each firm-year using a model of the determinants of a firm engaging in a high level of negative, irresponsible CSR activity.  Then, they match a **treatment firm** (one with a high level of negative CSR activities) to a **non-treatment firm** (one with a low level of, or no, negative CSR activities) by matching observations with the closest propensity scores. Hoi et al. (2013) then retest the relation between negative CSR activities and tax aggressiveness using this matched sample.
>
> These matching techniques help mitigate the researcher’s potential failure to consider certain firm characteristics that differ between    **treatment and non-treatment firms**
> (Dhaliwal et al., 2012).

Comment: A treatment firm is "one with a high level of, or no, negative CSR activities."  You have it in your question.  A statistician may tell you more about it.

Comment: The definition is given in the brackets immediately after the first use of the term, as is the proper practice. If that defintion is incomprehensible,it would appear that you had better reread the earlier sections of the book.

Comment: I've seen it, but cant get the exact meaning and cant find a substitution for it.this is the problem.

Comment: As I didn't get the answer...

Answer (score 2):

This is confusing because of the insane terminology of Propensity Score Matching. A "treatment firm" is a *firm* (ie company, etc), which is receiving a *treatment*.

In observational studies, such as this, unlike randomized experiments, the researcher does not randomly choose whether some intervention is applied to each subject, but instead observes whether or not each subject takes an action or not of their own volition. Those who take the action are called those who are *treated*. However, there is no one doing the treating, the subjects are deciding for themselves. This is a rather unconventional use of the word *treatment*, but it is the usual word to use in this context.

In your case, the researcher is performing a study in the effects of firms "with a high level of negative CSR activities", which is presumably some term of art in the dismal science of Economics. Those who undertake such activities, the *treatment firms*, are matched to similar firms who do not, *non-treatment firms*, and their performances are compared.

Comment: Perhaps one should avoid help centres unless one wants to lend a hand.

Comment: Good advice, in general, I think, @EdwinAshworth .

Comment: Please let me know if my editing/formatting made things worse!